Error on updating
When i run sudo apt upgrade, i receive this error
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.5.0-28-generic (--configure):
installed linux-image-6.5.0-28-generic package post-installation script subproc
ess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
memtest86+
linux-image-6.5.0-13-generic
linux-image-6.5.0-28-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

'''
Already run sudo apt autoremove and tried to purge those images,but doesn't work
